# PGFplots and table with different number of elements in columns

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am trying to plot a table where I have different number of elements in the columns. In the MWE, the pairs (x1,y1),...,(x4,y4) all have different number of elements, can I use PGFplots in such situation, ithout having to manually arrange the table or spit it in 4 different tables?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
x1 y1  x2 y2   x3 y3  x4 y4
1  0.5 1  0.2  1  0.1 1  0.3
2  0.7 2  0.4  2  0.2 2  0.5
3  0.3 3  0.6  3  0.4 3  0.6
4  0.1 4  0.3  4  0.4
       5  0.2  5  0.2
               6  0.2 
               7  0.1
}\mytable

\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.8,
    compat/show suggested version=false,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel={x-axis},ylabel={y-axis}]
    \addplot table[x=x1,y=y1] {\mytable};
    \addplot table[x=x2,y=y2] {\mytable};
    \addplot table[x=x3,y=y3] {\mytable};
    \addplot table[x=x4,y=y4] {\mytable};
    \legend{1,2,3,4}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you export the table with delimiters (`,` or Tab or …)? Otherwise, empty groups do help.

Comment: That table come from an external program, such as gnuplot or Matlab. The delimiter there is the space, like [x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4], so it would be better to keep it like in my question. However, other users may need with colons or tabs, therefore, it would also be useful an answer with those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you use a different `col sep`, you will need to use empty groups.

From the [`pgfplotstable`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplotstable) manual, section 2.1 “Text Table Input Format”, p. 5f:

> Furthermore, if you need empty cells in case `col sep≠space`, you have to provide `{}` to delimit such a cell since `col sep=space` uses at least one white space (consuming all following ones).

This is the usual way how TeX treats spaces.

An alternative solution would be to use a different column seperator, e.g. a comma:

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
x1, y1,x2, y2,x3, y3,x4, y4
 1,0.5, 1,0.2, 1,0.1, 1,0.3
 2,0.7, 2,0.4, 2,0.2, 2,0.5
 3,0.3, 3,0.6, 3,0.4, 3,0.6
 4,0.1, 4,0.3, 4,0.4,  ,
  ,   , 5,0.2, 5,0.2,  ,
  ,   ,  ,   , 6,0.2,  ,
  ,   ,  ,   , 7,0.1,  ,
}\mytable
```

(The spaces here are only for a visual reference.) For simple numbers that get parsed by `pgfplots` anyway, the additional spaces do not hurt, but for various other use cases, the option `/pgfplots/table/trim cells` might be helpful.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
x1 y1  x2 y2   x3 y3  x4 y4
1  0.5 1  0.2  1  0.1 1  0.3
2  0.7 2  0.4  2  0.2 2  0.5
3  0.3 3  0.6  3  0.4 3  0.6
4  0.1 4  0.3  4  0.4 {} {}
{} {}  5  0.2  5  0.2 {} {}
{} {}  {} {}   6  0.2 {} {} 
{} {}  {} {}   7  0.1 {} {}
}\mytable

\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.8,
    compat/show suggested version=false,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel={x-axis},ylabel={y-axis}]
    \addplot table[x=x1,y=y1] {\mytable};
    \addplot table[x=x2,y=y2] {\mytable};
    \addplot table[x=x3,y=y3] {\mytable};
    \addplot table[x=x4,y=y4] {\mytable};
    \legend{1,2,3,4}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Can you point me the page, just for future reference? Can I use the same approach in the original table that comes from the external program, I mean,  without using `pgfplotstable`?

Comment: @cacamailg I’ve added the reference. I’m not so sure what you mean with your second sentence. If I use the `{}`-filled table instead of `\mytable` in one of the `\addplot` commands, it works too.

Comment: My second sentence was exactly that! Thanks.